# Why doesn't getFirstResult() and getMaxResults( ) doesn't return the chunk of xth -to-yth rows from database?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

In my database there are rows as follows

```
article  lang     timestamp
0       English   2018-04-07 03:34:49 
1       English   2018-04-07 03:34:50
2       English   2018-04-07 03:34:51
3       English   2018-04-07 03:34:52
4       English   2018-04-07 03:34:53
5       English   2018-04-07 03:34:54
6       English   2018-04-07 03:34:55
7       English   2018-04-07 03:34:56
8       English   2018-04-07 03:34:57
9       English   2018-04-07 03:34:58
10      English   2018-04-07 03:34:59
```

My query is as follows

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select a from Article a where a.lang=:lang ORDER BY a.timeStamp ASC");
        query.setParameter("lang", lang);
        query.setFirstResult(startingRow);
        query.setMaxResults(endingRow);
        List<Article> result = (List<Article>) query.list(); 
        if(result.listIterator().hasNext()) {
            return result;
        }
```

When I send startingRow as 0 and endingRow as 4, I want results as

```
0 
1 
2 
3
```

When I send startingRow as 5 and endingRow as 9, I want results as

```
4 
5 
6 
7
```

But it is not coming as I expect. 
Its returning repetitive records in haphazard manner.
What am I doing wrong here?

My requirement is, I want results (records) in the sequence that I'm looking for. For eg, if I need records 55 to 65, then I need those records.

PS: I tried using query.setFetchSize(5), but it returns all records at one shot. I did some research and found out that if the driver doesn't support setFetchSize() it will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. This is how I solved it.

Hibernate lets you solve this by

query.setFirstResult(startingRow).setMaxResults(5);

where the `startingRow` is xth row mentioned and from that row it will return the next n(here 5) records.

Comment: How is this code different from the code in the question (that you claimed did not work)?

Comment: That's actually good question. But for some reason the first one didn't work and this gives the expected result.